# big_modeling.py not finding the offload_dir

Tags: python, peft

I'm trying to load a large model on my local machine and trying to offload some of the compute to my CPU since my GPU isn't great (Macbook Air M2). Here's my code:

```
from peft import PeftModel
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, GPTJForCausalLM, GenerationConfig
from transformers import BitsAndBytesConfig

quantization_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(llm_int8_enable_fp32_cpu_offload=True)

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("EleutherAI/gpt-j-6B")

tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
tokenizer.pad_token_id = tokenizer.eos_token_id

offload_folder="/Users/matthewberman/Desktop/offload"

model = GPTJForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    "EleutherAI/gpt-j-6B",
    device_map="auto",
    offload_folder=offload_folder,
    quantization_config=quantization_config
)

model = PeftModel.from_pretrained(model, "samwit/dolly-lora", offload_dir=offload_folder)
```

However, I get this error:

```
ValueError: We need an `offload_dir` to dispatch this model according to this `device_map`, the following submodules need to be offloaded: base_model.model.transformer.h.10, base_model.model.transformer.h.11, base_model.model.transformer.h.12, base_model.model.transformer.h.13, base_model.model.transformer.h.14, base_model.model.transformer.h.15, base_model.model.transformer.h.16, base_model.model.transformer.h.17, base_model.model.transformer.h.18, base_model.model.transformer.h.19, base_model.model.transformer.h.20, base_model.model.transformer.h.21, base_model.model.transformer.h.22, base_model.model.transformer.h.23, base_model.model.transformer.h.24, base_model.model.transformer.h.25, base_model.model.transformer.h.26, base_model.model.transformer.h.27, base_model.model.transformer.ln_f, base_model.model.lm_head.
```

I am definitely pointing to a valid offload directory as the previous method uses offload_folder successfully (I see things being put in there).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding " offload_folder='./', " to your peftModel.from_pretrained(...) argument.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).